# How to set alternate week days off in laravel using carbon package?

Tags: php, laravel, calendar, php-carbon

I've made a custom calendar and I want to set the alternate weekdays off like the image given bellow
how can we set that in larvel using carbon package?
[image]

Comment: Carbon is a library that deals with dates. It does not deal with user interfaces. You will need to show us how you are utilising carbon to produce that user interface and what you need to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$firstDate = Carbon::parse('2022-09-07');
$limit = '2022-12-31';

// List dates:
foreach ($firstDate->range($limit, '2 weeks') as $date) {
  echo $date; // 2022-09-07, 2022-09-21, 2022-10-05, ...
}

// Check if days is a day off:
function isDayOff($date) {
  return ((int) Carbon::parse('2022-09-07')->diffInDays($date)) % 14 === 0;
}

if (isDayOff('2022-10-19')) {
  echo "Yes 2022-10-19 is off";
}
```

Comment: good answer! thanks. Maybe u can know how i can check date is day off from array dayOffs?

Comment: Sorry, for example: 
```
function isDayOff(Carbon $date) {
  $dayOffs = [
    Carbon::create(2023, 1, 14),
    Carbon::create(2023, 1, 15),
];

foreach ($dayOffs as $dayOff) {
    if (Carbon::parse($date->toDateString())->diffInDays($dayOff) % 14 === 0) {
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have some advanced day-off handling, this might be of interest for you: https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-day